# Delete string between two commas

Tags: php, html

"This is a sentence, which is, weirdly seperated, by commas."

How can I delete the sentence between the 2nd comma and the third to get this sentence in PHP:

"This is a sentence, which is .... by commas."

Comment: Do you got any code to show us?

Comment: Take a look at php's [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
$sentence= "This is a sentence, which is, weirdly separated, by commas.";
$pieces = explode(",", $sentence);
echo $pieces[0] .', '. $pieces[1].', ...';
```

The explode function allows you to make an array of the string and separate each entry by what you put in quotes, in this case, a comma.

The last line concatenates the pieces of the array you want, leaving out the third section aka pieces[2].